# Xpath rule template is missing in SonarQube 5.1

Tags: templates, xpath, rules, sonarqube-5.0

I used to write Xpath custom rules up to SonarQube-3.7.4 but I don't find the way to write custom xpath rules in SonarQube 5.1.

I am able to write a custom rules plugin written in Java, but I would prefer using xpath if it is possible.

Any idea?

Comment: same problem with me

Answer (score 1):

Writing xpath rule in SQ5.1 is possible. 
Go to rules, select language xml, in search box , type xpath and click enter.
You will get xpath rule xml label , click on it , it will give you the interface to create xpath custom rule.(click on custom rule create tag)

Comment: Please note that you first have to install XML language support, otherwise it's impossible to select XML as language in the Rules view.